# Displaying a card/slide type news feed?

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to Android development. I'm completely stuck as to how to achieve my task. I want to display news (just some text) in a news feed. Is it possible to do this easily? For example like Facebook/Twitter's simple news feed, or even like Google Now's cards.
Should I achieve this through Android's components or should I use HTML?

Comment: We can sure help you but let's know **what you have tried so far**?

Answer (score 0):

well its simple, you could use `ListView` with custom `adapter` to achieve a news feed layout. look through `ListView` examples and guides:

[Android Guide to ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

[vogella guide.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

you'll find a lot of guides regards this.. just google them.